# Why do most news reading app like Pocket, Instapaper, Google Play Newsstand or NYTimes display articles as natives components instead of WebView?

Tags: android, performance, webview, android-webview

I used the android device monitor to check different News Reader UI and I realized that almost all of them are using Native components (ImageView, TextView, FrameLayout) to display their article instead of a WebView. I was wondering what could have motivated such a choice ?

A webService could return the article with a property containing the **extracted and formatted html** then the webView could be loaded from this plain html `String` with `java webView.loadData("<div></di>", .., ..)` right?

[image: Google Newsstand app]
[image: The NYTimes app]

Comment: The main reason is probably performance. Especially on older devices the WebView renders horribly slow. Have a look at following answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28789290/5199788

Answer (score -1):

Rendering a webview is slower than calling a web service . If you render webview it will load a whole lot component like css, javascript . But If you call web service , you will only get the data you want and then populate other component like textview , image view etc with .

Comment: What if the webService returns the article with a property containing the extracted html and then the webView can be loaded the from a plain html String like `webView.loadData("<div></di>", .., ..)` ?

Comment: are you saying extracted HTML without any CSS or JS ? Then it will be horrific to look at .

Comment: No you could have in your local assets an html template file containing the shared page configuration "header, css, font" and where you could insert the content your received from the backend